# Is there an equation to check for a single x & y coordinate in a responsive image at different sizes?

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates, responsive

I have a flex image that is responsive to the screen size.
For simplicities sake, let's say the width and height start at 50px / 100px that can grow to 500px / 1000px.

I want to  track a point in the image through an onClick handler. Let's say the x & y coordinates of that point is 10 / 10 at the minimum image size. As the div grows that point changes relative to the size of the image. Is there an equation that can check to see if, on a subsequent click, the new coordinates match the minimum image size coordinates of 10 / 10?

Comment: "_responsive to the screen size_" How exactly? Are you loading a new image for different screen sizes, or are you just adjusting the with/height properties of the image?

Comment: It is the same image. The width property is 100% of the flex container.

Comment: Store an original dimension of the image (ex. `.naturalWidth`), and calculate a scale based on the original width and the current width of the flex container.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your help. I'll give that a go.